# How to check each line from an website/php file and Enable/disable Components C#

Tags: c#, php

I try to make a function that allows me to enable and disable multiple components from a server. Preferably from one php file.

Example: 
 Website Side

```
AdminPanelEnabled=True
UserIPPanelEnabled=False
GuestPanelEnabled=True
```

(On the website there is no other code just what you see above)

If it is set to true on the server/website it will enable the component or if set to false it will disable the component.

Tries and fails

```
Checker = new WebClient().DownloadString("URL/Checker.php");
        if (Checker == "AdminPanelEnabled=True")
        {
            AdminPanel.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            AdminPanel.Enabled = false;
        }


        if (Checker == "UserIPPanelEnabled=True")
        {
            UserIPPanel.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UserIPPanel.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (Checker == "GuestPanelEnabled=True")
        {
            GuestPanel.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GuestPanel.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking/what the problem is. What is the result/behaviour right now? What is unexpected?

Comment: Is the problem reading the 3 lines? What are you getting for `Checker`?

Comment: _"On the website there is no other code just what you see above"_ - So the website consists of only those three lines (which isn't even PHP)? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Since there is no reaction I voted to close with "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: I was in the middle of editing the post to show you with whats, you should give user time to edit posts. Not just shut the topic instantly.

Comment: Your problem doesn't really seem to be related to PHP ( at least as far as I understood it), that probably makes it confusing.

Comment: It seems to me, that you want to configure a back end systems written in c#. Therefore i would have answered it with a link pointing to the official  [ASP.Net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1). But since no technology stack is given, i think it's hard to answer that question. Not even an error message is provided.

Answer (score 0):

The file you provided consists of multiple lines, so you have to separate the lines first and then check every single line. So, maybe something like this works?

```
string[] lines = new WebClient().DownloadString("Checker.php")
                 .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] config = line.Split('=');
    if (config[0] == "AdminPanelEnabled")
    {
        AdminPanel.Enabled = bool.Parse(config[1]);
    }
    else if (config[0] == "UserIPPanelEnabled")
    {
        UserIPPanel.Enabled = bool.Parse(config[1]);
    }
    else if (config[0] == "GuestPanelEnabled")
    {
        GuestPanel.Enabled = bool.Parse(config[1]);
    }
}
```